# <span> tag selection problem within anchor using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, selector, html

I have facing  a problem to select span tag using jquery. Please give a solution.
code:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <a href="#Document1">Document 1
       <span id="tab_close> x </span>
     </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want to get a specific span within an anchor? Does it have an id? Does the anchor have one? There's a thousand ways to do this. Please be more specific.

Comment: You forgot to elaborate more about the functional requirement and the problem. We now only know that you have "a" problem and how your HTML code look like. But that gives us really nothing to work with.

Comment: Dear sir,

Basically I want  to create close able tab dynamically. Suppose Tab Title Document 1, Document 2 ..... etc . <span> use for close (x).
I want to select <span> when user click on the Close (x)  on the tab. 
If any clarification please notify me ...
I am very sorry because My English knowledge is very poor. 
Thanks
MH

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tab_close')
```

...if, by selecting, you mean getting the jQuery object representing that node.

Comment: Without any more information from the OP about any specific problem, this IS the correct answer. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using jQuery if all you're doing is selecting an element by id.  No need to include the framework for something built into Javascript.

```
document.getElementById("tab_close");
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close the id

```
<span id="tab_close"> x </span>
```